# Loading of Haskell source file is too slow in vim

Tags: haskell, vim

After waiting for a while (2 or 3 minutes) to open .hs file in vim, I am getting following errors:

```
Error detected while processing ~/.vim/bundle/haskellmode-vim/ftplugin/haskell_doc.vim:
line  111:
haskell_doc.vim can't find locaton of html documentation (set g:haddock_docdir).
ghcmod: vimproc.vim is not installed!
```

I am getting these errors even though I disabled haskellmode, vimproc and ghcmod plugins. Here is a snippet from my .vimrc (I am using vundle plugin to load plugins into the vim):

```
" Haskell plugins
" Plugin 'lukerandall/haskellmode-vim'
" Plugin 'eagletmt/ghcmod-vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'eagletmt/neco-ghc'
"Plugin 'dag/vim2hs'
"Plugin 'Shougo/vimproc.vim'
```

Could you please help me figure out why my vim is so slow and throwing those errors? Thanks.

Comment: I hate to point out the obvious, but if haskellmode is still running scripts you quite apparently didn't disable it correctly.

Comment: You might try asking at the [VI & VIm SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:PluginClean` to delete plugins after you comment them out of your `.vimrc`. See also `:help vundle` for further details.